# Memory Allocation in an array of structures

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
airPdata **airport = malloc(sizeof(airport) * (50+1));
    printf("Passes airPdata **airport\n");
//  buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * (50+1));

// puts the strings into char line
while(fgets(line, 1024, fp) != NULL)
{
    // has pointer value point to line
    value = line;
    printf("Before creating space for struct members\n");
    // creating space for the struct members
    airport[j]->LocID = malloc(sizeof(char)*(50+1));

    airport[j]->fieldName = malloc(sizeof(char)*(50+1));

    airport[j]->city = malloc(sizeof(char)*(50+1));

    printf("after\n");
```

I'm trying to create an array of structures, but I just can't figure out how to allocate memory for the members of the struct.. It keeps segfaulting.  LocID, fieldName and city are all char*

EDIT***
I figured out the problem. Using a double pointer doesn't need to allocate airport, but the members of airport still need to be allocated.

// allocates memory for the struct
    airPdata **airport;

//  buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * (50+1));

```
// puts the strings into char line
while(fgets(line, 1024, fp) != NULL)
{
    // has pointer value point to line
    value = line;
printf("Yes\n");
    // creating space for the struct members
    airport[j]->LocID = malloc(sizeof(char)*(50+1));    
    airport[j]->fieldName = malloc(sizeof(char)*(50+1));
    airport[j]->city = malloc(sizeof(char)*(50+1));
    j++;
 }
```

However, the program seg faults when it goes back around the while loop for the second time and encounters `airport[j]->LocID = malloc`

Comment: `airPdata *airport = malloc(sizeof(*airport) * (50+1));` not `**`

Comment: I originally used airPdata airport[MAX]; because I want to use an array of structs, but changed it to a double pointer

Comment: `airPdata *airport[MAX]` is the array of pointers, not an array of structs

Comment: Make up your mind--airport can be either an array of pointers, which you allocate and then allocate each element as well; or it can be just a flat array of structs, allocated once (and then use airport[i].city instead of ->)

Comment: I want to use an array of pointers, not structs then, sorry

Comment: "program seg faults when it goes back around the while loop for the second time and encounters `airport[j]->LocID = malloc`" implies `airport[j]` was not assigned/allocated correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's code biggest failing is not allocating memory for each `airport[i]`

---

With `airPdata **airport` and [I want to use an array of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822462/memory-allocation-in-an-array-of-structures#comment86660712_49822462), code needs to allocate at 2 levels and use an *arrray*.

Memory for array `airport[]`
Memory allocated & assigned to each element of `airport[i]`  (**OP missed this part.**)
Memory allocated & assigned to the various members like `airport[i].LocID`

---

Memory for array `airport` is easy as shown below.  `airPdata **airport` is a pointer and not an array.  Instead use an *array* as that is the stated design goal.

```
// define array element count. 
#define AIRPORT_N 100 
// Declare the array.
airPdata *airport[AIRPORT_N];
// Keep tack of how much of the array is used.
size_t n = 0;
```

Now assign, read and begin filling the array, allocating as needed.

```
#define AIRPORT_STRING_SIZE (50 + 1)
char line[1024];
while(n < AIRPORT_N && fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
  // Allocate memory for one element of `airport`
  // Notice no cast nor type coded here.
  airport[n] = malloc(sizeof *(airport[n]));
  if (airport[n] == NULL) {
    // Something simple for now.
    fprintf(stderr, "OOM\n");
    break;
  }
  // Create space for each string,  
  // TODO: add check for Out-of-Memory
  airport[n]->LocID = malloc(AIRPORT_STRING_SIZE);
  airport[n]->fieldName = malloc(AIRPORT_STRING_SIZE);
  airport[n]->city = malloc(AIRPORT_STRING_SIZE);

  // Code to parse `line` into `airport[n]` members.

  // Usually the parsing happens first and if successful, the above allocations occur.

  // If the `LocID` string (and others) need not change then 
  //   use below to allocate a right-sized memory
  //   after parsing instead of allocating to some max size, like above.
  airport[n]->LocID = strdup(LocID_string);

  n++;
}
```

Later free it all

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  free(airport[i]->LocID);
  free(airport[i]->fieldName);
  free(airport[i]->city);
  free(airport[i]);
}
```

---

Detail: Notice the subtle error in the following.  It allocates to the size of `airport`, which is type  `airPdata **`.

Instead, it should allocate to the size of `* airport`, which is type `airPdata *`.

Very commonly, object pointers of all types are the same size, yet this same-ness is not specified across all type in C.

Better to allocate to the size of the de-referenced pointer that to a type.  It more likely coded right, easier to review and maintain.

```
// airPdata **airport = malloc(sizeof(airport) * (50+1));
airPdata **airport = malloc(sizeof *airport * (50+1));
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I had to malloc the individual airport[j] as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing 2 ways of doing this.

A you have a contiguous array of airports

```
airports -----> ap1 | ap2 | ap3
```

B You have an array of pointers to airports (not necessarily next to each other in memory

```
airports --> aptr1 | aptr2 | aptr3
               |        |        |
               v        v        v
              ap1       ap2     ap3
```

your malloc mixes A and B. if you want A

do

```
airPdata *airport = malloc(sizeof(airport) * (50+1));
```

if you want B do

```
airPdata **airport = malloc(sizeof(airport*) * (50+1));
```

Then later you will have to allocate an airport object too for each pointer slot.

Comment: indeed he did, but his code is a mixture of both. I wanted him to be sure he was aiming at what he intends